# get list of php files consuming resources

Tags: php, debian, performance, apache-2.2

Does there exist a way to output a list of currently executing PHP files, in Apache in debian? (and if it is possible, also listing the resources used by that instance).

We are having some performance issues and need some external way -- without touching the php code -- to monitor what file/process of the site is consuming a specific amount of resources.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Apache has an ExtendedStatus that you can enable that will show you details about the requests it is handling at that moment.

Comment: i enabled it and tried to see the status with `apachectl status` but it didn't show me the name of the files, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: you should use `apachectl fullstatus` to see the files being requested